# Cloud service project template not getting listed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud, project-template

I have installed Windows Azure SDK on my machine on top of VS 2010 SP1. "Windows Azure project" template is listed (file->new project) but "Cloud Service Project" template is not getting listed. Do I have to install anything else? Thanks.

Comment: Whether Project templates "Windows Azure project" and "Cloud Service Project" are same in VS 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe "Windows Azure project" is correct, and "Cloud Service Project" is just old terminology. I don't have a project template called that either.

Comment: thanks. I am using "Windows Azure Project" template and it seems to work fine for me :)  Any idea if this change is with .net 4.0/V2010?

Comment: Not sure when that changed... but it could be as long as a year or so ago.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also install the Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio?  I usually choose the tooling option as it also includes the SDK.  Pro tip: use the Web Platform Installer and it will also setup any other dependencies you need.

Click the 'Get Started' link from here to use WebPI installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks dunnry. I had installed necessary SDK. smarx answer resolved my problem. +1 for your reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on VS 2012, switch the .NET Framework version at the top to 4.0. I was totally flummoxed by this silly issue and even filed a connect bug!

The UI needs updating to discard the Framework version filter and have the supported frameworks listed in a column. Choosing the Framework to target should be moved down to the bottom where other pre-create config options are set.